# Updating Pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to solve an issue in which, I will be iterating over a dataframe (DF1) row by row, and updating another dataframe(DF2) based on a condition. 
The condition is that if the identifier value (DF1.Col1) already exists in the DF.Col2, then update all other values in DF2 from DF1. Else, the row gets appended.

for this I am able to reach till:

```
for idx in DF1.index:
if DF1['col1'][idx] in DF2.col1.values:
    '''stuck here, not sure how to replace all values of DF2 from DF1'''
else:
     DF2 = DF2.append(DF1.iloc[idx:idex+1])
```

Please suggest.

Sample data could be:

```
DF1 
    Col1 Col2 Col3
    1    11   aa
    2    22   bb
    3    33   cc

DF2
   Col1 Col2 Col3
    1    01   xx
    2    02   yy
    4    04   zz
```

result should be

```
DF2

    Col1 Col2 Col3
    1     11   aa
    2     22   bb
    4     04   zz
    3     33   cc
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide the data and show your intended before and after?

Comment: Can you please write original DF2 also?

Comment: From your example, it seems like you are just dropping duplicates from DF1 with keyword “keep=‘last’”.